# mdadm: no devices listed in conf file were found (Debian 11)

Tags: linux, debian, boot, dual-boot

Earlier today, I ran into a recurring issue with my dual boot system where it boots straight into Windows and ignores GRUB. I fixed this as I usually do: going into the UEFI and manually adding GRUB as a boot option (precisely, \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi). This reinstated GRUB, but upon trying to boot into Debian, I ran into the following error:

`mdadm: No devices listed in conf file were found.`

After this appeared a number of times, the following appeared:

```
Gave up waiting for root device.
Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/5887d2e0-bae1-4ce8-ac6f-168fb183d7b0 does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!
```

I am not sure how to edit `rootdelay`, but I tried running `rootdelay=10` and `exit` and it did not work. When I run `cat /proc/cmdline` I get a long answer that looks to be correct but I will not reproduce unless someone asks (since I'm typing on my phone).

I think it might not be accessing my drives, because when I run `cat /proc/mdstat`, I get a list of personalities, an empty list of unused devices, and nothing else. However, I am having trouble diagnosing the problem as I am relatively new to Linux. Any help on resolving or even understanding this would be appreciated.

Note that booting into Windows is working, and that booting into the Debian recovery mode is not. Also note that booting both into Debian and Windows was working roughly an hour ago.

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions`, `ls /dev/disk/by-`, `mdadm --examine`, `dmesg`, ...?